# HTML5 input not working with keyboad's 10 key

Tags: django, angular, text, input

I am having an odd issue that I can't explain with one of the inputs of type text I have in one of my Django app's templates. I can enter in numbers on a mac using the number keys on the top, but when someone uses a keyboard that has a 10 key, and enters a number using that 10 key, the input doesn't register it at all ? A couple other things to note is that I am using Angular on the frontend of the app, and have inline javascript for quick validation, we had an issue with our Zip input truncating leading zeros because it was initially of type 'number'. Has anyone faced this issue before in the past ?

HTML Input

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="javascript: if ((event.which < 48 && event.which != 8) || event.which > 57) event.preventDefault();" placeholder="-" ng-model="homeState.search.zip" maxlength="5"
                                   oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"/>
```

I thought maybe the key codes were different when using the 10 key, but they are exactly the same.

Comment: What keyboards have a 10 key? Do you mean F10?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the term 10-key refers to a keyboard's number pad ie "A tenkeyless keyboard"

Comment: Oh I see, you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad

Comment: It's possible that numlock is off. Make sure that the numlock light on the keyboard is on by toggling it with the numlock key before entering a number or else windows will treat it as an arrow key.

Comment: Is there a way to allow inputs with type number to allow leading zeros as a value when the page is initially loaded? I think that way it wouldn't matter, I just couldn't figure out how to get past that issue.